# Hold wood while using sled

Tags: wood, table-saw

How can I hold down my wood when using the sled other than holding it with my hand?

[image]

I have this push stick. Maybe I can modify it to my needs?

[image]

Comment: I like the 3d push block - https://www.leevalley.com/en-ca/shop/tools/power-tool-accessories/safety/49712-grr-ripper-system?item=03J8010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get fancy, some folks have installed a plexiglass blade guard extending between front and back fences, riding above the normal heights of the blade, to help them remember to keep fingers clear. You could get insanely fancy by putting sides in that which slide down to the board's surface

You could temporarily attach the piece to the sled using hot glue or a weak double-sided tape, as you would attack a template.

But I think for reasonable-sized pieces, most folks just hold the piece down as they would when using a simple miter gauge.

The bigger danger is probably that as you finish the cut, the blade comes through the back of the sled. If you hit careless about where you were pushing the sled, that could be ugly. To reduce that risk, it's not uncommon to build a box onto the back of the sled to create a protected zone.

Websearching for sled designs should find examples of these. There are other solutions, but those strike me as simplest to implement.

If you *really* want hold-downs, I've seen sleds with T-tracks embedded into them which could be used for work-holding attachments. Unless you're frequently doing something complicated, that strikes me as probably being overkill.

Comment: I have a variable temp glue gun. Using it would be problematic as it adheres VERY well. Sometimes I have to use a wood chisel to separate the pieces.

Comment: Trick I saw from one of the magazines: painter's tape on both pieces, then glue the tape backs together. Similar to the old trick of temporary joint of gluing to s piece of paper, but easier cleanup. Not convinced it's needed here, though. What would you do if just cutting with a miter gauge and long fence?

Comment: Also, different hot glues are available with different characteristics. The one I've got, used sparingly, would hold fine but pop free easily.

Answer (score 0):

Something like a drill press clamp would be the best, but do not know if it can mounted to the sled.

A piece of dowel or 2x2 with a plate on the bottom will keep hands/fingers further away.

Screwing the piece to the sled will also work.